# Spark streaming wordcount using filstream doesn't print result

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, filestream

I'm using file as Spark streaming, i want to count the words in the stream, but the application prints nothing, here's my code. I'm using Scala on Cloudera environment

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 import org.apache.spark.streaming._
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

 object TwitterHashtagStreaming {

 def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterHashtagStreaming").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");

val streamingC = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(5))

val streamLines = streamingC.textFileStream("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/wordstream")
val words = streamLines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

 counts.print()

 streamingC.start()
 streamingC.awaitTermination()
}

 }
```

Comment: What is it printing? Any error?

Comment: No, just time, as if counts is empty
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1506415275000 ms
-------------------------------------------

Comment: First try to print streamLines before doing word count to ensure whether data has been read or not.

Comment: It's empty too..i don't know what's the problem with reading. the file has data, and the file path is correct.

Comment: Do check again your file path. There is no issue with code. Complete example https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/HdfsWordCount.scala

Comment: @raam86 this worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please carefully refer the [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream):

```
def textFileStream(directory: String): DStream[String]
```

> Create a input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for
>   new files and reads them as text files (using key as LongWritable,
>   value as Text and input format as TextInputFormat). Files must be
>   written to the monitored directory by "moving" them from another
>   location within the same file system. File names starting with . are
>   ignored.

**In a word, it is a change detector, you must start your streaming service, then write your data in your monitor directory.**

This semantic will simulate the **"stream concept"** when it is actually deployed in production environment, for example, **network packets will gradually income like your files.**